# Example replicate' from "Learn you some Haskell" chapter on Recursion

Tags: haskell

I was going through http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion
and implemented replicate' like

```
replicate' :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
replicae' 0 _ = []
replicate' n x
  | n < 0  = []
  | n > 0  = [x] ++ replicate' (n - 1) x
```

Decided to try it with negative repetition number, got error:

```
ghci> replicate' -1 42

<interactive>:35:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Num t0)
        arising from a type ambiguity check for
        the inferred type for ‘it’
      from the context: (Ord i, Num i, Num t, Num (t -> i -> a -> [a]),
                         Num (i -> a -> [a]))
        bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                   forall {i} {t} {a}.
                   (Ord i, Num i, Num t, Num (t -> i -> a -> [a]),
                    Num (i -> a -> [a])) =>
                   i -> a -> [a]
        at <interactive>:35:1-16
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall {i} {t} {a}.
              (Ord i, Num i, Num t, Num (t -> i -> a -> [a]),
               Num (i -> a -> [a])) =>
              i -> a -> [a]
```

I thought: "Maybe I'm doing something wrong?" and tried the book's example; with the same result

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

GHCi, version 9.2.4

What's wrong with the code, and why even the book's example isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your expression:

```
replicate' -1 42
```

the operator `-` is being misinterpreted as a binary `-` operator, so this is equivalent to:

```
replicate' - (1 42)
```

so Haskell is trying to apply the "function" `1` to the argument `42` and then subtract that result from the function `replicate'`.  The result is an inscrutable error message.

Try:

```
replicate' (-1) 42
```

and it should work fine.

Do note that your original `replicate'` definition has misspelled the function as `replicae'` in the second line, so make sure that's fixed, too.

Comment: If they add `{-# LANGUAGE NegativeLiterals #-}` or enable `:set -XNegativeLiterals` it will work!